# Usind 3d array to index 4d array

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, python-xarray

I have a 4d-xarray with dimensions `I[t, z, y, x]` and a 3d-xarray with dimensions `Z[t, y, x]`. `Z` are the indices I need for dimension z in `I`. Now I want to get the values `I[t, Z[t,y,x], y, x]` and write them into a new xarray of size `O[t, y, x]`.

In principal I solved the problem by using for-loops, but that is way too slow (a lot and large arrays). Is there a way to do this without for-loops?

Example code doing what I want but to slow:

```
def get_field_at_levels(array, levels):
    shape = array.shape
    array_out = np.zeros_like(levels)
    for t in range(shape[0]):
        for x in range(shape[2]):
            for y in range(shape[3]):
                if np.isnan(levels[t, x, y]):
                    array_out[t, x, y]==float('nan')
                else:
                    array_out[t, x, y] = array[t, int(levels[t, x, y]), x, y]
    return array_out
```

Comment: the answer is probably yes, but it's tough to deal with abstractions like this without some examples. could you provide some examples of inputs and outputs to validate results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted all my xarrays to numpy.arrays using numpy.asarray. Now the program is fast enough using loops. Below an example script using random numbers.
In my actual data I have indices out of range (-1). In this case I want NaN as result.

```
import numpy as np
import time

tsize = 1
xsize = 40
ysize = 240
zsize = 260

def val_at_lev(data, Ind):
    sh=data.shape
    data2=np.empty([sh[0],sh[1]+1,sh[2],sh[3]])
    data2[:,0:sh[1],:,:]=data
    data2[:,sh[1],:,:]='nan'
    out=np.asarray(np.zeros_like(Ind))
    erg=np.asarray([data2[t,Ind[t,0,j,k],j,k] for t in range(sh[0]) for j in range(sh[2]) for k in range(sh[3])])
    out = erg.reshape(tsize,1,ysize,zsize)
    return out

# Main program
Ind=np.random.randint(-1,xsize,[tsize,1,ysize,zsize])
data=np.random.uniform(0,100,[tsize,xsize,ysize,zsize])
start_time = time.time()
erg=val_at_lev(data,Ind)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```